# why a named constructor in a class with final propertieses most has all the final properties in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

In this class I dont want to (chatCard.person) named constructor has subtitle property.Because I dont need it.But as you can see I have this error :All final variables must be initialized, but 'subtitle' isn't.
Try adding an initializer for the field.
I know that If I remove final keyWord from its definition in third line the error will remove But then the class isnt immutable.
So any idea?

Comment: https://dart.dev/language/constructors#initializer-list

Comment: Just have your named constructor explicitly initialize it to an empty string in its initializer list.

Comment: But I don't want the named constructor has this property at all

Comment: replace `required this.subtitle` with `this.subtitle = 'default value'`

Answer (score 1):

You can follow like

```dart
  const ChatCard.person({
    super.key,
     .....
  }) : subtitle = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a factory constructor that doesn't include the `subtitle` property:

```dart
class ChatCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatCard._({
    this.title,
    this.subtitle,
    this.lastSeenTime,
    this.lastMessageTime,
    this.pic,
    this.unSeenMessageNumber,
    this.memberSubscribeNumber,
    this.isOnline,
    this.seenStatus,
  });

  factory ChatCard.person({
    required String? title,
    required String? lastSeenTime,
    required String? lastMessageTime,
    required String? pic,
    required String? unSeenMessageNumber,
    required String? memberSubscribeNumber,
    required bool? isOnline,
    required bool? seenStatus,
  }) =>
      ChatCard._(
        title: title,
        lastSeenTime: lastSeenTime,
        lastMessageTime: lastMessageTime,
        pic: pic,
        unSeenMessageNumber: unSeenMessageNumber,
        memberSubscribeNumber: memberSubscribeNumber,
        isOnline: isOnline,
        seenStatus: seenStatus,
      );

  final String? title;
  final String? subtitle;
  final String? lastSeenTime;
  final String? lastMessageTime;
  final String? pic;
  final String? unSeenMessageNumber;
  final String? memberSubscribeNumber;
  final bool? isOnline;
  final bool? seenStatus;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```